# Instance not created

Tags: openstack

I installed OpenStask. All modules were installed without problems. Volums, network, subnet, ports, images, flavors are all created without errors. But the instance is not created; upon creation, it immediately gives an error:
 fault | {u'message ': u'Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exhausted all hosts available for retrying build failures for instance 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a. ', U'code': 500, u'details ': u' File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages /nova/conductor/manager.py ", line 627, in build_instances \ n raise exception.MaxRetriesExceeded (reason = msg) \ n ', u'created': u'2019-08-19T12: 54: 37Z '}

I ask for help in solving the problem.
Thank!!!

In the logs /var/log/nova/nova-compute.log there is this:
If necessary, I will provide all the additional necessary information.

I checked the neutron section in nova.conf with the definition of user_domain_name = Default and project_domain_name = Default, everything is fine there.

```
In the logs /var/log/nova/nova-compute.log there is this:

2019-08-19 15:54:32.151 1437 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-5138fd5d-0f86-4a7e-ad64-06e739d6c0ae 85e9ede8610641dcb75e67b76e0a8833 bf6641220c7747fa9810449e45b7a232 - 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8] [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] Attempting claim on node compute.test.local: memory 300 MB, disk 3 GB, vcpus 1 CPU
2019-08-19 15:54:32.153 1437 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-5138fd5d-0f86-4a7e-ad64-06e739d6c0ae 85e9ede8610641dcb75e67b76e0a8833 bf6641220c7747fa9810449e45b7a232 - 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8] [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] Total memory: 4095 MB, used: 512.00 MB
2019-08-19 15:54:32.153 1437 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-5138fd5d-0f86-4a7e-ad64-06e739d6c0ae 85e9ede8610641dcb75e67b76e0a8833 bf6641220c7747fa9810449e45b7a232 - 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8] [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] memory limit not specified, defaulting to unlimited
2019-08-19 15:54:32.153 1437 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-5138fd5d-0f86-4a7e-ad64-06e739d6c0ae 85e9ede8610641dcb75e67b76e0a8833 bf6641220c7747fa9810449e45b7a232 - 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8] [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] Total disk: 16 GB, used: 0.00 GB
2019-08-19 15:54:32.154 1437 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-5138fd5d-0f86-4a7e-ad64-06e739d6c0ae 85e9ede8610641dcb75e67b76e0a8833 bf6641220c7747fa9810449e45b7a232 - 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8] [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] disk limit not specified, defaulting to unlimited
2019-08-19 15:54:32.154 1437 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-5138fd5d-0f86-4a7e-ad64-06e739d6c0ae 85e9ede8610641dcb75e67b76e0a8833 bf6641220c7747fa9810449e45b7a232 - 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8] [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] Total vcpu: 4 VCPU, used: 0.00 VCPU
2019-08-19 15:54:32.154 1437 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-5138fd5d-0f86-4a7e-ad64-06e739d6c0ae 85e9ede8610641dcb75e67b76e0a8833 bf6641220c7747fa9810449e45b7a232 - 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8] [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] vcpu limit not specified, defaulting to unlimited
2019-08-19 15:54:32.156 1437 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-5138fd5d-0f86-4a7e-ad64-06e739d6c0ae 85e9ede8610641dcb75e67b76e0a8833 bf6641220c7747fa9810449e45b7a232 - 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8] [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] Claim successful on node compute.test.local
2019-08-19 15:54:32.437 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-5138fd5d-0f86-4a7e-ad64-06e739d6c0ae 85e9ede8610641dcb75e67b76e0a8833 bf6641220c7747fa9810449e45b7a232 - 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8] Instance failed network setup after 1 attempt(s): PortNotUsable: Port 62347407-0d4e-438c-adf3-e0fd1011a6cd not usable for instance 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a.
2019-08-19 15:54:32.437 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-08-19 15:54:32.437 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1521, in _allocate_network_async
2019-08-19 15:54:32.437 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager     resource_provider_mapping=resource_provider_mapping)
2019-08-19 15:54:32.437 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/neutronv2/api.py", line 1064, in allocate_for_instance
2019-08-19 15:54:32.437 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager     context, instance, neutron, requested_networks, attach=attach))
2019-08-19 15:54:32.437 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/neutronv2/api.py", line 749, in _validate_requested_port_ids
2019-08-19 15:54:32.437 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager     instance=instance.uuid)
2019-08-19 15:54:32.437 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager PortNotUsable: Port 62347407-0d4e-438c-adf3-e0fd1011a6cd not usable for instance 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a.
2019-08-19 15:54:32.437 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager 
2019-08-19 15:54:32.609 1437 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-5138fd5d-0f86-4a7e-ad64-06e739d6c0ae 85e9ede8610641dcb75e67b76e0a8833 bf6641220c7747fa9810449e45b7a232 - 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8] [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] Creating image
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-5138fd5d-0f86-4a7e-ad64-06e739d6c0ae 85e9ede8610641dcb75e67b76e0a8833 bf6641220c7747fa9810449e45b7a232 - 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8] [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] Instance failed to spawn: PortNotUsable: Port 62347407-0d4e-438c-adf3-e0fd1011a6cd not usable for instance 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a.
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2495, in _build_resources
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]     yield resources
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2256, in _build_and_run_instance
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]     block_device_info=block_device_info)
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 3167, in spawn
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]     mdevs=mdevs)
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 5498, in _get_guest_xml
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]     network_info_str = str(network_info)
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/model.py", line 570, in __str__
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]     return self._sync_wrapper(fn, *args, **kwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/model.py", line 553, in _sync_wrapper
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]     self.wait()
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/model.py", line 585, in wait
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]     self[:] = self._gt.wait()
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 180, in wait
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]     return self._exit_event.wait()
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/event.py", line 132, in wait
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]     current.throw(*self._exc)
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 219, in main
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]     result = function(*args, **kwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/utils.py", line 800, in context_wrapper
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1538, in _allocate_network_async
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]     six.reraise(*exc_info)
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1521, in _allocate_network_async
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]     resource_provider_mapping=resource_provider_mapping)
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/neutronv2/api.py", line 1064, in allocate_for_instance
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]     context, instance, neutron, requested_networks, attach=attach))
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/neutronv2/api.py", line 749, in _validate_requested_port_ids
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a]     instance=instance.uuid)
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] PortNotUsable: Port 62347407-0d4e-438c-adf3-e0fd1011a6cd not usable for instance 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a.
2019-08-19 15:54:35.251 1437 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] 
2019-08-19 15:54:35.255 1437 INFO nova.compute.manager [req-5138fd5d-0f86-4a7e-ad64-06e739d6c0ae 85e9ede8610641dcb75e67b76e0a8833 bf6641220c7747fa9810449e45b7a232 - 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8] [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] Terminating instance
2019-08-19 15:54:35.264 1437 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-] [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] Instance destroyed successfully.
2019-08-19 15:54:35.265 1437 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-5138fd5d-0f86-4a7e-ad64-06e739d6c0ae 85e9ede8610641dcb75e67b76e0a8833 bf6641220c7747fa9810449e45b7a232 - 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8] [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] Deleting instance files /var/lib/nova/instances/1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a_del
2019-08-19 15:54:35.265 1437 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-5138fd5d-0f86-4a7e-ad64-06e739d6c0ae 85e9ede8610641dcb75e67b76e0a8833 bf6641220c7747fa9810449e45b7a232 - 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8] [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] Deletion of /var/lib/nova/instances/1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a_del complete
2019-08-19 15:54:35.385 1437 INFO nova.compute.manager [req-5138fd5d-0f86-4a7e-ad64-06e739d6c0ae 85e9ede8610641dcb75e67b76e0a8833 bf6641220c7747fa9810449e45b7a232 - 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8 387dbcd0ba384713ad51666944113ab8] [instance: 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a] Took 0.12 seconds to destroy the instance on the hypervisor.
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api [-] Unable to clear device ID for port '62347407-0d4e-438c-adf3-e0fd1011a6cd': BadRequest: Expecting to find domain in user. The server could not comply with the request since it is either malformed or otherwise incorrect. The client is assumed to be in error. (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-c1d9a12b-4f86-45d7-a879-a4f6cf22c3a3)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/neutronv2/api.py", line 686, in _unbind_ports
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     port_client.update_port(port_id, port_req_body)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/neutronv2/api.py", line 127, in wrapper
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     ret = obj(*args, **kwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 808, in update_port
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     revision_number=revision_number)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/neutronv2/api.py", line 127, in wrapper
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     ret = obj(*args, **kwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 2389, in _update_resource
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     return self.put(path, **kwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/neutronv2/api.py", line 127, in wrapper
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     ret = obj(*args, **kwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 363, in put
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     headers=headers, params=params)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/neutronv2/api.py", line 127, in wrapper
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     ret = obj(*args, **kwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 331, in retry_request
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     headers=headers, params=params)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/neutronv2/api.py", line 127, in wrapper
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     ret = obj(*args, **kwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 282, in do_request
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     headers=headers)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 340, in do_request
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     return self.request(url, method, **kwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 328, in request
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     resp = super(SessionClient, self).request(*args, **kwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 237, in request
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     return self.session.request(url, method, **kwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 704, in request
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     auth_headers = self.get_auth_headers(auth)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 1097, in get_auth_headers
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     return auth.get_headers(self, **kwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/plugin.py", line 95, in get_headers
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     token = self.get_token(session)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 88, in get_token
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     return self.get_access(session).auth_token
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 134, in get_access
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     self.auth_ref = self.get_auth_ref(session)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/generic/base.py", line 208, in get_auth_ref
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     return self._plugin.get_auth_ref(session, **kwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/v3/base.py", line 178, in get_auth_ref
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     authenticated=False, log=False, **rkwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 1045, in post
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     return self.request(url, 'POST', **kwargs)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 890, in request
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api     raise exceptions.from_response(resp, method, url)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api BadRequest: Expecting to find domain in user. The server could not comply with the request since it is either malformed or otherwise incorrect. The client is assumed to be in error. (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-c1d9a12b-4f86-45d7-a879-a4f6cf22c3a3)
2019-08-19 15:54:36.424 1437 ERROR nova.network.neutronv2.api
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Error logs :

**Port 62347407-0d4e-438c-adf3-e0fd1011a6cd not usable for instance 1451041c-da04-478c-93dd-0acb60dd149a**

Please share how you are creating this instance.

Comment: Hi, my answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, I tried to create instances with the following commands:
openstack server create --image 27bb3ced-fa95-4f69-add7-5ea5020b8292 --flavor 0d9318e0-7867-4465-ba54-f0242af3b527 --nic net-id = 3acc836d-e9f2-4d97-81fa-6299f6cbc308 myinstance1

openstack server create --volume cb81de0e-65a4-4f09-aa4d-701e0728de79 --flavor 0d9318e0-7867-4465-ba54-f0242af3b527 --nic net-id = 3acc836d-e9f2-4d97-81fa-6299f6cbc308inst

openstack server create --image 27bb3ced-fa95-4f69-add7-5ea5020b8292 --flavor 0d9318e0-7867-4465-ba54-f0242af3b527 --port 62347407-0d4e-438c-adf3-e0fd1011a6cd myinstance3

For all teams, the result is the same.